# Setting a delegate property

Tags: c#, properties, delegates, variable-assignment

```
    public class Red : CollisionClass
    {
        public CollisionChecker Algorithm; //this is a delegate that checks the collision
        public Red()
        {
            Algorithm = BaseAlgorithm; //PROBLEM, i dont know how to assign it correctly
        }
        public bool BaseAlgorithm(CollisionClass field)
        {
            return true;//in this method there will be an algorithm to check collision
        }
    }
    public delegate bool CollisionChecker(CollisionClass x,CollisionClass y);
```

in this script:
there is a class called Red, which is a derived class from an abstract class called CollisionClass. the collision class can check whether its colliding with another derived class. to do so, an algorithm delegate can be stored in the algorithm property, the idea is that if i ever make an expansion of this class, i can create new algorithms and store them in the property, but i don't know how to assign a method as a delegate to the property.

Thank you for reading my question

Comment: Your delegate isn't a property, it's a field.  Also, it should probably be an `event` rather than a field or property of a delegate type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is fine, but the method you are trying to assign to the delegate doesn't match the declaration of the delegate type.

The `CollisionChecker` delegate is defined as taking two `CollisionClass` instances as parameters, and returning true.  Your method (`BaseAlgorithm`) only accepts a single `CollectionClass`.

That being said, in this case, it sounds like you don't need to use delegates at all.  You could easily eliminate the delegate, and just make your method `virtual`, as this will allow you to override it in subclasses later, providing the same "expansion" mechanism you're trying to achieve here:

```
 public virtual bool Algorithm(CollisionClass field)
 {
     return true;
 }
```

With this, subclasses could override the `Algorithm` method (though I would consider a better name, such as `Collides`, etc) as needed.